# How to get month name out of date field

Tags: sql, date, datetime

I'm trying to build a query that gives me a year month field with month names instead of the numbers. The output should be similar to this:

```
Year/month field  | Sum field
Januari 2014          100
Februari 2014       12300
Maart 2014           3234
April 2014           4964
```

I've searched for the way to get the the month name but I must be doing something wrong because I constantly get the error that datename is not a function or an sql error 1064. This i what i've tried:

```
SELECT id, 
       YEAR(report_date) AS YEAR, 
       MONTH(report_date) AS MONTH,
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, (MONTH(report_date))) ,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, report_date)) SUM(num) AS participants_month
FROM participants
WHERE unit_id = 10
GROUP BY unit_id,
  MONTH(report_date)
ORDER BY report_date ASC;
```

Tried to make this question as clear as possible. If something isn't clear tell me and I'll try to explain it. Really hope someone could point me out in the right direction.

Comment: What database system do you use? MYSQL? SQL Server?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry. What's the best way to see which system it is. I believe mysql. I'm also using mysqlnotifier and there it says mysql56. I installed it along mysql workbench

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server you use DATENAME(month, date):
[SQL Server Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ace32/2/0)

But in MySQL you use MONTHNAME(date):
[MySQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ace32/1/0)

From the error you are receiving I guess you do not use SQL Server as your database management system, so in MySQL you should use [MONTHNAME(date)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname).

Comment: Thank you very much. The MONTHNAME(date) did it.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, I suppose, you are using MySQL.But the DATENAME() is Transact-SQL function.

In MySQL, you can use

```
  MONTH(yourdate)
```

instead

Comment: As shown in my example I'm currently using that format to get the month number. It doesn't show the month name.

Comment: MONTH returns month number, not name, in MySQL. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month